# Identify translation string and disadvantages of inline translation

Tags: localisation, inline-translations

I have successfully translated Magento 2 by following this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtVperaeOac

The translation pack that I downloaded was not perfect but a good start and I have added translation strings to the csv file that I uploaded under
/applications/mvjskrbmgy/public_html/app/i18n/myname/sv_se
and it have worked as soon as I have reindexed and flushed the cache.

However I cant find some of the untranslated strings in the file and I wonder  if there is a way to identify the specific string. I know I can use inline translation but when I have done that in the past it often leads to other strings malfunction, I dont know why and would love to know about the difference between inline translation and translating by using the csv file. I know that inline translation only works for the current storeview but is there any other difference?

An example of a string that I cant find in the translation csv file is the label "Details" of the product page. See image. How can I identify that string?

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this case i recommend to translate inline in:

Store > Configuration > advanced > Developer Translate Inline

Enable For storefront Yes.

Now flush the cache and go to the view, you can see a red square, click there and translate